# Understanding maven dependencies on a webapp

Tags: java, web-services, maven, web-applications

This is my first time with dealing web-app and maven. Now I've a **restful web-service** project and I'm looking **its server side** pom.xml file. In there there are 4 different dependencies related with web app. These are :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.2.v20150730</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.2.v20150730</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.2.v20150730</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now, as far  as I know, there are 3 entities that are required for running a webapp.  These are `Web server` , `web container (servlet engine)`  and `servlet`. (At least for my application these are required)

So, I think  dependencies in the pom.xml should correspond one of these dependencies. However there isn't one to one match since there are 4 dependency but 3 logical entity. (Of course  of of these dependencies in my pom.xml file  might be redundant (not used) )

My question is which of these dependencies corresponds to which logical entity I list above ? And also what is the difference between jetty-servlet and jetty-servlets dependencies ?

**Edit**

To test whether there is an unused dependency or not, I commented the 4th dependency (jersey-container-jetty-http) and still my application works fine. 
Therefore, I think  :

- jetty-server corresponds to  web-server
- jetty-servlet corresponds to servlet engine ( i.e. web container)
- jetty-servlets corresponds to servlet

**EDIT2**

I'm confused now. When I look at my project folders, I have found a web.xml file :

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myproject.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.myproject.rest.rest.filter.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Now here, it is written that servlet name is `jersey-server`  (com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer). But in the pom.xml , jetty is defined as web container ?

Comment: No wonder commenting that 4th dependency didn't change anything. Jersey is the reference implementation for JAX-RS, to do RESTful webservices. Apparently you don't need that. Before you posted this question, did you read the rather complete jetty documentation at all? Search for existing questions on jetty and maven?

Comment: @Gimby , yes I tried to understand all of the sources I read but as I said its my first time with these topics. Therefore documentations are hard to understand for me. Btw, I have a web-service which makes cors request.

Comment: I don't know what to answer at this point, you're confused by not understanding properly what core concepts are (such as a servlet) and because you're trying to reason all this from the perspective of components of Jetty. I'm sure Jetty itself subdivides into isolated components such as a server and a servlet container, but if you had properly studied the basics of Java web programming in general, you'd have understood this is irrelevant to you and its all just smaller parts of the same whole - a server that acts as a servlet container, which is Jetty.